# C# Как узнать разрядности чужого exe или чужого процесса?

Tags: c#, процесс, exe

Как в C# узнать разрядность exe файла??? Если это не возможно, то как узнать разрядность процесса - 32бит или 64бит?

Comment: своего или чужого?

Comment: Чужого процесса или exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для EXE-файла можно узнать разрядность с помощью функции [GetBinaryType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364819%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public enum BinaryType : uint
{
    SCS_32BIT_BINARY = 0,
    SCS_64BIT_BINARY = 6,
    SCS_DOS_BINARY = 1,
    SCS_OS216_BINARY = 5,
    SCS_PIF_BINARY = 3,
    SCS_POSIX_BINARY = 4,
    SCS_WOW_BINARY = 2
}

public class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetBinaryType(string lpApplicationName,
       out BinaryType lpBinaryType);

    void PrintExeType(string ExeFilePath)
    {
        BinaryType bt;
        bool res = Native.GetBinaryType(ExeFilePath, out bt);

        if (res == false) MessageBox.Show("Not executable");
        else
        {
            switch (bt)
            {
                case BinaryType.SCS_32BIT_BINARY: MessageBox.Show("32-bit executable"); break;
                case BinaryType.SCS_64BIT_BINARY: MessageBox.Show("64-bit executable"); break;
                default: MessageBox.Show("Other executable"); break;
            }
        }
    }              

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace Is64Bit
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName + " is " + (p.IsWin64Emulator() ? string.Empty : "not ") + "32-bit");
                }
                catch (Win32Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.NativeErrorCode != 0x00000005)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool IsWin64Emulator(this Process process)
        {
            if ((Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5)
                || ((Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5) && (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1)))
            {
                bool retVal;

                return NativeMethods.IsWow64Process(process.Handle, out retVal) && retVal;
            }

            return false; // not on 64-bit Windows Emulator
        }
    }

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr process, [Out] out bool wow64Process);
    }
}
```

Ссылка на источник [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-determine-programmatically-whether-a-particular-process-is-32-bit-or-64-b)

**Примечание.** Код ошибки 0x00000005 - `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (возникает при попытке обратится к системному процессу без привилегий администратора).

Comment: Спасибо! С наступающим! :)